# How to condtionally check two condtions within a JSX expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

I am trying to test the validity of two condtions within a jsx expression within react. However, when I add my second expression to check for, I don't get an expected result. Rather, recieve the result of the expression as a `0` or `1` value.

This is my Current JSX:

```js
{expression1 && (
  <button>Click me!</button>
)}
```

This is what I want, but this does not render correctly.

```js
{expression1 & expression2  && (
  <button>Click me!</button>
)}
```

There must be a proper way to fix this. I am thinking that this is a syntactical issue.

Comment: Typo here: `{expression1 & expression2  && (`. It should be `{expression1 && expression2  && (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to use the double ampersand operator:

```
{expression1 && expression2 && (
  <button>Click me!</button>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I must  have gotten confused with the second pair of `&&`'s